# React Custom component not getting rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

***Custom component is not getting render on UI**, also note that I have element by id: root

```
function CComponent(prop) {
  const element = (
    <div className="container">
      <div className={prop.classname}>{prop.content}</div>
    </div>
  );

  return element;
}

const helloElement = (
  <CComponent>{{ classname: "xyz", content: "helloWorld" }}</CComponent>
);

console.log(helloElement);
ReactDOM.render(helloElement, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass props to component like this:

```
const helloElement = <CComponent classname='xyz' content='helloWorld' />
```

Answer (score 1):

*You are passing your values as children, to pass values as props, you do this:*
`<CComponent classname='xyz' content='helloWorld' />`

Answer (score 0):

According to react doc :

```
React.createElement(
   type,
   [props],
   [...children]
)
```

`<CComponent>{{ classname: "xyz", content: "helloWorld" }}</CComponent>` this was compiled by babel to :

```
var helloElement = React.createElement(CComponent, null, {
  classname: 'xyz',
  content: 'helloWorld'
})
```

But `<CComponent classname='xyz' content='helloWorld' />`

got compiled to

```
var helloElement= React.createElement(CComponent, {
  classname: "xyz",
  content: "helloWorld"
})
```

Hence   was rendered on UI

Answer (score 0):

With babel 7 and react >= 16 it wont work. CComponent gets a children prop with {classname,content} object.

You can try change the syntax a bit and it will render perfectly to

```js
<CComponent {...{ className: "xyz", content: "helloWorld" }} />
```